# Third Vertex of a Triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

If I have two vertices of a triangle $(x_1,y_1)$ & $(x_2,y_2)$ and I know the lengths of three sides of the triangle $a,b,c$ , how can I find the third vertex ? Is there any derived formula?

Comment: I see one issue right away: If the given lengths are unequal, the third vertex will not be uniquely defined.

Comment: @dbx that is not really an issue, is it?

Comment: Well the question asks for a formula. This means there will be *two* formulas. You tell me if that's an issue, I guess.

Comment: @dbx a formula can give more than one pair of vertices

Comment: Ok, your view is clear. This is a strange thing to argue about. I notice your answer doesn't contain such a formula.

Answer (score 3):

The third vertex will lie at the intersection point(s) of two circles centered at the two given vertices and radii equal to corresponding side lengths.

Clearly there'll be two possible positions for third vertex.

So one can write equations of two circles $S_1=0$ and $S_2=0$, equate them to get equation of common chord $L=0$ and further solve for intersection of $L$ with $S_i$'s.

Here is a diagram explaining the situation.

[image]